# MD5 Crypto API returns incorrect hash for certain plaintexts

Tags: c, winapi, cryptography, md5, cryptoapi

I'm attempting to use the Microsoft crypto APIs to compute an MD5 hash, but I'm getting incorrect hashes:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <wincrypt.h>

char* HashMD5(char* data, DWORD *result)
{
    DWORD dwStatus = 0;
    DWORD cbHash = 16;
    int i = 0;
    HCRYPTPROV cryptProv;
    HCRYPTHASH cryptHash;
    BYTE hash[16];
    char *hex = "01234567879abcdef";
    char *strHash = "00000000000000000000000000000000";
    if(!CryptAcquireContext(&cryptProv, NULL, MS_DEF_PROV, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT))
    {
        dwStatus = GetLastError();
        printf("CryptAcquireContext failed: %d\n", dwStatus);
        *result = dwStatus;
        return NULL;
    }
    if(!CryptCreateHash(cryptProv, CALG_MD5, 0, 0, &cryptHash))
    {
        dwStatus = GetLastError();
        printf("CryptCreateHash failed: %d\n", dwStatus);
        CryptReleaseContext(cryptProv, 0);
        *result = dwStatus;
        return NULL;
    }
    if(!CryptHashData(cryptHash, (BYTE*)data, strlen(data), 0))
    {
        dwStatus = GetLastError();
        printf("CryptHashData failed: %d\n", dwStatus);
        CryptReleaseContext(cryptProv, 0);
        CryptDestroyHash(cryptHash);
        *result = dwStatus;
        return NULL;
    }
    if(!CryptGetHashParam(cryptHash, HP_HASHVAL, hash, &cbHash, 0))
    {
        dwStatus = GetLastError();
        printf("CryptGetHashParam failed: %d\n", dwStatus);
        CryptReleaseContext(cryptProv, 0);
        CryptDestroyHash(cryptHash);
        *result = dwStatus;
        return NULL;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < cbHash; i++)
    {
        strHash[i*2]     = hex[hash[i] >> 4];
        strHash[(i*2)+1] = hex[hash[i] & 0xF];
    }
    CryptReleaseContext(cryptProv, 0);
    CryptDestroyHash(cryptHash);
    return strHash;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    DWORD result = 0;
    char* hash;
    if(argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: crypto.exe <word>\n");
        return 0;
    }
    hash = HashMD5(argv[1], &result);
    if(result == 0)
    {
        printf("Hash of '%s' is: %s\n", argv[1], hash);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Failed! Result: %d\n", result);
    }
    return result;
}
```

The code executes fine, no error message is printed, but the returned hash value is incorrect for certain plaintexts:

```
$ ./crypto.exe test
Hash of 'test' is: 078e6abc4621c373b9cd4d832627a4e6

$ ./crypto.exe StackOverflow
Hash of 'StackOverflow' is: 84c7cb17766b446e5d4084d8ebd87e82
```

The latter is correct, but the former should be `098f6bcd4621d373cade4e832627b4f6`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: this is a job for the code review site.

Comment: @bmargulies: No, code review is not for failing code. It really belongs here.

Comment: According to the code review FAQ, they review code that is working but perhaps not optimal. They also state that code review is not for trouble-shooting. This code is broken and requires trouble-shooting.

Comment: Actually both hashes are wrong (although not completely), so I suspect that the conversion to hex is faulty.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
char *hex = "01234567879abcdef";
```

You have an error in that line.

It should read:

```
char *hex = "0123456789abcdef";
```

Comment: \*facepalm\*... Thanks for spotting that one!

Answer (score 4):

```
strHash[i*2]     = hex[hash[i] >> 4];
strHash[(i*2)+1] = hex[hash[i] & 0xF];
```

`strHash` points to a string literal. string literal are non-modifiable. Modifying a string literal is undefined behavior.

Comment: I patched the code to use `malloc()` instead, but still have the same problem.

Comment: +1: not the problem (as it turns out), but an excellent point nonetheless.

Comment: @Dave the problem is he is returning `strHash` at the end of the function, so he cannot do that.