# Compute MD5 hash value by c++ WinAPI

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, hash, md5

My C++ app needs to compute an MD5 hash value. Currently, it is done by OpenSSL, and I want to use WinAPI - to avoid dependencies on external libraries.

I wrote this code:

```
HCRYPTPROV hCryptProv = NULL;
HCRYPTHASH hHash = NULL;
HCRYPTHASH hHexHash = NULL;
HASH HA1;
HASHHEX HA1HEX;
DWORD data = HASHLEN;

// Get a handle to a cryptography provider context.
if(!CryptAcquireContext(&hCryptProv, NULL, NULL, PROV_RSA_FULL, 0))
{
    goto err;
}

// Acquire a hash object handle.
if(!CryptCreateHash(hCryptProv, CALG_MD5, 0, 0, &hHash))
{
    goto err;
}

CryptHashData(hHash, (const BYTE *)str, strlen(str), 0);
```

now, the strange thing is that sometimes it works well, but in other times the CryptAcquireContext returns NTE_BAD_KEYSET error, that according to MSDN
:

> The key container could not be opened. A common cause of this error is that the key container does not exist. To create a key container, call CryptAcquireContext using the CRYPT_NEWKEYSET flag. This error code can also indicate that access to an existing key container is denied. Access rights to the container can be granted by the key set creator by using CryptSetProvParam.
>
> Blockquote

Now my questions are:

1. If I call CryptSetProvParam, what exactly does it do? Is it normal that simple application changes the OS settings?
2. Is there any less difficult way to compute MD5 in C++ windows?

I'll appreciate if someone gives me good advice on what to do.
Thanks.

Comment: A public domain dedicated implementation [can be found here](http://openwall.info/wiki/people/solar/software/public-domain-source-code/md5).

Comment: thanks, but as for now I prefer not to implement it myself

Comment: You wouldn't be implementing it yourself. Just drop md5.c and md5.h into your project and call the functions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So, I found an example that does what you want at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa382380%28VS.85%29.aspx

Looking at their code, the difference I see is this line:

Theirs: CryptAcquireContext(&hCryptProv, NULL, NULL, PROV_RSA_FULL, **CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT**)

Yours:  CryptAcquireContext(&hCryptProv, NULL, NULL, PROV_RSA_FULL, 0)

So, reading up on that flag, I find this information:

CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT: This option is intended for applications that are using ephemeral keys, or applications that do not require access to persisted private keys, such as applications that perform only hashing, encryption, and digital signature verification. Only applications that create signatures or decrypt messages need access to a private key. In most cases, this flag should be set.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379886%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

So, it looks like you are trying to get access to information you don't need, and the request is denied.  So the best option is to tell Windows you don't need that information by including that flag.

Answer (score 6):

I like to use [`PROV_RSA_AES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa387447%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [`CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379886%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), because the most of the hashes are supported.

Here is a working example:

```
#include <Wincrypt.h>

enum HashType
{
  HashSha1, HashMd5, HashSha256
};

std::string GetHashText( const void * data, const size_t data_size, HashType hashType )
{
  HCRYPTPROV hProv = NULL;

  if ( ! CryptAcquireContext( &hProv, NULL, NULL, PROV_RSA_AES, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT ) ) {
    return "";
  }

  BOOL hash_ok = FALSE;
  HCRYPTPROV hHash = NULL;
  switch ( hashType ) {
  case HashSha1 : hash_ok = CryptCreateHash( hProv, CALG_SHA1, 0, 0, &hHash ); break;
  case HashMd5 : hash_ok = CryptCreateHash( hProv, CALG_MD5, 0, 0, &hHash ); break;
  case HashSha256 : hash_ok = CryptCreateHash( hProv, CALG_SHA_256, 0, 0, &hHash ); break;
  }

  if ( ! hash_ok ) {
    CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
    return "";
  }

  if ( ! CryptHashData( hHash, static_cast<const BYTE *>(data), data_size, 0 ) ) {
    CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
    CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
    return "";
  }

  DWORD cbHashSize = 0, dwCount = sizeof(DWORD);
  if( ! CryptGetHashParam( hHash, HP_HASHSIZE, (BYTE *)&cbHashSize, &dwCount, 0 ) ) {
    CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
    CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
    return "";
  }

  std::vector<BYTE> buffer( cbHashSize );
  if ( ! CryptGetHashParam( hHash, HP_HASHVAL, reinterpret_cast<BYTE*>( &buffer[0] ), &cbHashSize, 0) ) {
    CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
    CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
    return "";
  }

  std::ostringstream oss;

  for ( std::vector<BYTE>::const_iterator iter = buffer.begin(); iter != buffer.end(); ++iter ) {
    oss.fill('0');
    oss.width(2);
    oss << std::hex << static_cast<const int>(*iter);
  }

  CryptDestroyHash(hHash);
  CryptReleaseContext(hProv, 0);
  return oss.str();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The following 'MD5.h' file can be created and a simple code could be used.

**main.cpp**

```
#include "md5.h"
int main()
{
MD5 md5;
puts( md5.digestString( "HELLO THERE I AM MD5!" ) ) ;
// print the digest for a binary file on disk.
puts( md5.digestFile( "C:\\WINDOWS\\notepad.exe" ) ) ;
return 0;
}
```

**MD5.h**

```
#ifndef MD5_H
#define MD5_H
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#pragma region MD5 defines
// Constants for MD5Transform routine.
#define S11 7
#define S12 12
#define S13 17
#define S14 22
#define S21 5
#define S22 9
#define S23 14
#define S24 20
#define S31 4
#define S32 11
#define S33 16
#define S34 23
#define S41 6
#define S42 10
#define S43 15
#define S44 21

static unsigned char PADDING[64] = {
    0x80, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
};

// F, G, H and I are basic MD5 functions.
#define F(x, y, z) (((x) & (y)) | ((~x) & (z)))
#define G(x, y, z) (((x) & (z)) | ((y) & (~z)))
#define H(x, y, z) ((x) ^ (y) ^ (z))
#define I(x, y, z) ((y) ^ ((x) | (~z)))

// ROTATE_LEFT rotates x left n bits.
#define ROTATE_LEFT(x, n) (((x) << (n)) | ((x) >> (32-(n))))

// FF, GG, HH, and II transformations for rounds 1, 2, 3, and 4.
// Rotation is separate from addition to prevent recomputation.
#define FF(a, b, c, d, x, s, ac) { \
  (a) += F ((b), (c), (d)) + (x) + (UINT4)(ac); \
  (a) = ROTATE_LEFT ((a), (s)); \
  (a) += (b); \
  }
#define GG(a, b, c, d, x, s, ac) { \
  (a) += G ((b), (c), (d)) + (x) + (UINT4)(ac); \
  (a) = ROTATE_LEFT ((a), (s)); \
  (a) += (b); \
      }
#define HH(a, b, c, d, x, s, ac) { \
  (a) += H ((b), (c), (d)) + (x) + (UINT4)(ac); \
  (a) = ROTATE_LEFT ((a), (s)); \
  (a) += (b); \
      }
#define II(a, b, c, d, x, s, ac) { \
  (a) += I ((b), (c), (d)) + (x) + (UINT4)(ac); \
  (a) = ROTATE_LEFT ((a), (s)); \
  (a) += (b); \
      }
#pragma endregion

typedef unsigned char BYTE;

// POINTER defines a generic pointer type
typedef unsigned char *POINTER;

// UINT2 defines a two byte word
typedef unsigned short int UINT2;

// UINT4 defines a four byte word
typedef unsigned long int UINT4;


// convenient object that wraps
// the C-functions for use in C++ only
class MD5
{
private:
    struct __context_t {
        UINT4 state[4];                                   /* state (ABCD) */
        UINT4 count[2];        /* number of bits, modulo 2^64 (lsb first) */
        unsigned char buffer[64];                         /* input buffer */
    } context;

#pragma region static helper functions
    // The core of the MD5 algorithm is here.
    // MD5 basic transformation. Transforms state based on block.
    static void MD5Transform(UINT4 state[4], unsigned char block[64])
    {
        UINT4 a = state[0], b = state[1], c = state[2], d = state[3], x[16];

        Decode(x, block, 64);

        /* Round 1 */
        FF(a, b, c, d, x[0], S11, 0xd76aa478); /* 1 */
        FF(d, a, b, c, x[1], S12, 0xe8c7b756); /* 2 */
        FF(c, d, a, b, x[2], S13, 0x242070db); /* 3 */
        FF(b, c, d, a, x[3], S14, 0xc1bdceee); /* 4 */
        FF(a, b, c, d, x[4], S11, 0xf57c0faf); /* 5 */
        FF(d, a, b, c, x[5], S12, 0x4787c62a); /* 6 */
        FF(c, d, a, b, x[6], S13, 0xa8304613); /* 7 */
        FF(b, c, d, a, x[7], S14, 0xfd469501); /* 8 */
        FF(a, b, c, d, x[8], S11, 0x698098d8); /* 9 */
        FF(d, a, b, c, x[9], S12, 0x8b44f7af); /* 10 */
        FF(c, d, a, b, x[10], S13, 0xffff5bb1); /* 11 */
        FF(b, c, d, a, x[11], S14, 0x895cd7be); /* 12 */
        FF(a, b, c, d, x[12], S11, 0x6b901122); /* 13 */
        FF(d, a, b, c, x[13], S12, 0xfd987193); /* 14 */
        FF(c, d, a, b, x[14], S13, 0xa679438e); /* 15 */
        FF(b, c, d, a, x[15], S14, 0x49b40821); /* 16 */

        /* Round 2 */
        GG(a, b, c, d, x[1], S21, 0xf61e2562); /* 17 */
        GG(d, a, b, c, x[6], S22, 0xc040b340); /* 18 */
        GG(c, d, a, b, x[11], S23, 0x265e5a51); /* 19 */
        GG(b, c, d, a, x[0], S24, 0xe9b6c7aa); /* 20 */
        GG(a, b, c, d, x[5], S21, 0xd62f105d); /* 21 */
        GG(d, a, b, c, x[10], S22, 0x2441453); /* 22 */
        GG(c, d, a, b, x[15], S23, 0xd8a1e681); /* 23 */
        GG(b, c, d, a, x[4], S24, 0xe7d3fbc8); /* 24 */
        GG(a, b, c, d, x[9], S21, 0x21e1cde6); /* 25 */
        GG(d, a, b, c, x[14], S22, 0xc33707d6); /* 26 */
        GG(c, d, a, b, x[3], S23, 0xf4d50d87); /* 27 */
        GG(b, c, d, a, x[8], S24, 0x455a14ed); /* 28 */
        GG(a, b, c, d, x[13], S21, 0xa9e3e905); /* 29 */
        GG(d, a, b, c, x[2], S22, 0xfcefa3f8); /* 30 */
        GG(c, d, a, b, x[7], S23, 0x676f02d9); /* 31 */
        GG(b, c, d, a, x[12], S24, 0x8d2a4c8a); /* 32 */

        /* Round 3 */
        HH(a, b, c, d, x[5], S31, 0xfffa3942); /* 33 */
        HH(d, a, b, c, x[8], S32, 0x8771f681); /* 34 */
        HH(c, d, a, b, x[11], S33, 0x6d9d6122); /* 35 */
        HH(b, c, d, a, x[14], S34, 0xfde5380c); /* 36 */
        HH(a, b, c, d, x[1], S31, 0xa4beea44); /* 37 */
        HH(d, a, b, c, x[4], S32, 0x4bdecfa9); /* 38 */
        HH(c, d, a, b, x[7], S33, 0xf6bb4b60); /* 39 */
        HH(b, c, d, a, x[10], S34, 0xbebfbc70); /* 40 */
        HH(a, b, c, d, x[13], S31, 0x289b7ec6); /* 41 */
        HH(d, a, b, c, x[0], S32, 0xeaa127fa); /* 42 */
        HH(c, d, a, b, x[3], S33, 0xd4ef3085); /* 43 */
        HH(b, c, d, a, x[6], S34, 0x4881d05); /* 44 */
        HH(a, b, c, d, x[9], S31, 0xd9d4d039); /* 45 */
        HH(d, a, b, c, x[12], S32, 0xe6db99e5); /* 46 */
        HH(c, d, a, b, x[15], S33, 0x1fa27cf8); /* 47 */
        HH(b, c, d, a, x[2], S34, 0xc4ac5665); /* 48 */

        /* Round 4 */
        II(a, b, c, d, x[0], S41, 0xf4292244); /* 49 */
        II(d, a, b, c, x[7], S42, 0x432aff97); /* 50 */
        II(c, d, a, b, x[14], S43, 0xab9423a7); /* 51 */
        II(b, c, d, a, x[5], S44, 0xfc93a039); /* 52 */
        II(a, b, c, d, x[12], S41, 0x655b59c3); /* 53 */
        II(d, a, b, c, x[3], S42, 0x8f0ccc92); /* 54 */
        II(c, d, a, b, x[10], S43, 0xffeff47d); /* 55 */
        II(b, c, d, a, x[1], S44, 0x85845dd1); /* 56 */
        II(a, b, c, d, x[8], S41, 0x6fa87e4f); /* 57 */
        II(d, a, b, c, x[15], S42, 0xfe2ce6e0); /* 58 */
        II(c, d, a, b, x[6], S43, 0xa3014314); /* 59 */
        II(b, c, d, a, x[13], S44, 0x4e0811a1); /* 60 */
        II(a, b, c, d, x[4], S41, 0xf7537e82); /* 61 */
        II(d, a, b, c, x[11], S42, 0xbd3af235); /* 62 */
        II(c, d, a, b, x[2], S43, 0x2ad7d2bb); /* 63 */
        II(b, c, d, a, x[9], S44, 0xeb86d391); /* 64 */

        state[0] += a;
        state[1] += b;
        state[2] += c;
        state[3] += d;

        // Zeroize sensitive information.
        memset((POINTER)x, 0, sizeof(x));
    }

    // Encodes input (UINT4) into output (unsigned char). Assumes len is
    // a multiple of 4.
    static void Encode(unsigned char *output, UINT4 *input, unsigned int len)
    {
        unsigned int i, j;

        for (i = 0, j = 0; j < len; i++, j += 4) {
            output[j] = (unsigned char)(input[i] & 0xff);
            output[j + 1] = (unsigned char)((input[i] >> 8) & 0xff);
            output[j + 2] = (unsigned char)((input[i] >> 16) & 0xff);
            output[j + 3] = (unsigned char)((input[i] >> 24) & 0xff);
        }
    }

    // Decodes input (unsigned char) into output (UINT4). Assumes len is
    // a multiple of 4.
    static void Decode(UINT4 *output, unsigned char *input, unsigned int len)
    {
        unsigned int i, j;

        for (i = 0, j = 0; j < len; i++, j += 4)
            output[i] = ((UINT4)input[j]) | (((UINT4)input[j + 1]) << 8) |
            (((UINT4)input[j + 2]) << 16) | (((UINT4)input[j + 3]) << 24);
    }
#pragma endregion


public:
    // MAIN FUNCTIONS
    MD5()
    {
        Init();
    }

    // MD5 initialization. Begins an MD5 operation, writing a new context.
    void Init()
    {
        context.count[0] = context.count[1] = 0;

        // Load magic initialization constants.
        context.state[0] = 0x67452301;
        context.state[1] = 0xefcdab89;
        context.state[2] = 0x98badcfe;
        context.state[3] = 0x10325476;
    }

    // MD5 block update operation. Continues an MD5 message-digest
    // operation, processing another message block, and updating the
    // context.
    void Update(
        unsigned char *input,   // input block
        unsigned int inputLen) // length of input block
    {
        unsigned int i, index, partLen;

        // Compute number of bytes mod 64
        index = (unsigned int)((context.count[0] >> 3) & 0x3F);

        // Update number of bits
        if ((context.count[0] += ((UINT4)inputLen << 3))
            < ((UINT4)inputLen << 3))
            context.count[1]++;
        context.count[1] += ((UINT4)inputLen >> 29);

        partLen = 64 - index;

        // Transform as many times as possible.
        if (inputLen >= partLen) {
            memcpy((POINTER)&context.buffer[index], (POINTER)input, partLen);
            MD5Transform(context.state, context.buffer);

            for (i = partLen; i + 63 < inputLen; i += 64)
                MD5Transform(context.state, &input[i]);

            index = 0;
        }
        else
            i = 0;

        /* Buffer remaining input */
        memcpy((POINTER)&context.buffer[index], (POINTER)&input[i], inputLen - i);
    }

    // MD5 finalization. Ends an MD5 message-digest operation, writing the
    // the message digest and zeroizing the context.
    // Writes to digestRaw
    void Final()
    {
        unsigned char bits[8];
        unsigned int index, padLen;

        // Save number of bits
        Encode(bits, context.count, 8);

        // Pad out to 56 mod 64.
        index = (unsigned int)((context.count[0] >> 3) & 0x3f);
        padLen = (index < 56) ? (56 - index) : (120 - index);
        Update(PADDING, padLen);

        // Append length (before padding)
        Update(bits, 8);

        // Store state in digest
        Encode(digestRaw, context.state, 16);

        // Zeroize sensitive information.
        memset((POINTER)&context, 0, sizeof(context));

        writeToString();
    }

    /// Buffer must be 32+1 (nul) = 33 chars long at least 
    void writeToString()
    {
        int pos;

        for (pos = 0; pos < 16; pos++)
            sprintf(digestChars + (pos * 2), "%02x", digestRaw[pos]);
    }


public:
    // an MD5 digest is a 16-byte number (32 hex digits)
    BYTE digestRaw[16];

    // This version of the digest is actually
    // a "printf'd" version of the digest.
    char digestChars[33];

    /// Load a file from disk and digest it
    // Digests a file and returns the result.
    char* digestFile(char *filename)
    {
        Init();

        FILE *file;

        int len;
        unsigned char buffer[1024];

        if ((file = fopen(filename, "rb")) == NULL)
            printf("%s can't be opened\n", filename);
        else
        {
            while (len = fread(buffer, 1, 1024, file))
                Update(buffer, len);
            Final();

            fclose(file);
        }

        return digestChars;
    }

    /// Digests a byte-array already in memory
    char* digestMemory(BYTE *memchunk, int len)
    {
        Init();
        Update(memchunk, len);
        Final();

        return digestChars;
    }

    // Digests a string and prints the result.
    char* digestString(char *string)
    {
        Init();
        Update((unsigned char*)string, strlen(string));
        Final();

        return digestChars;
    }
};

#endif
```

Comment: Have not tested if this works but I like this approach the most, since it even eliminates the dependency on WinApi. This minimizes portability issues, when porting to other architectures.

Answer (score 2):

I got this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702054/md5-crypto-api-returns-incorrect-hash-for-certain-plaintexts)

but I made some changes in order to run this function on my side, hope it might help

```
char* HashMD5(char* data, DWORD *result)
{
    DWORD dwStatus = 0;
    DWORD cbHash = 16;
    int i = 0;
    HCRYPTPROV cryptProv;
    HCRYPTHASH cryptHash;
    BYTE hash[16];
    char *hex = "0123456789abcdef";
    char *strHash;
    strHash = (char*)malloc(500);
    memset(strHash, '\0', 500);
    if (!CryptAcquireContext(&cryptProv, NULL, MS_DEF_PROV, PROV_RSA_FULL, CRYPT_VERIFYCONTEXT))
    {
        dwStatus = GetLastError();
        printf("CryptAcquireContext failed: %d\n", dwStatus);
        *result = dwStatus;
        return NULL;
    }
    if (!CryptCreateHash(cryptProv, CALG_MD5, 0, 0, &cryptHash))
    {
        dwStatus = GetLastError();
        printf("CryptCreateHash failed: %d\n", dwStatus);
        CryptReleaseContext(cryptProv, 0);
        *result = dwStatus;
        return NULL;
    }
    if (!CryptHashData(cryptHash, (BYTE*)data, strlen(data), 0))
    {
        dwStatus = GetLastError();
        printf("CryptHashData failed: %d\n", dwStatus);
        CryptReleaseContext(cryptProv, 0);
        CryptDestroyHash(cryptHash);
        *result = dwStatus;
        return NULL;
    }
    if (!CryptGetHashParam(cryptHash, HP_HASHVAL, hash, &cbHash, 0))
    {
        dwStatus = GetLastError();
        printf("CryptGetHashParam failed: %d\n", dwStatus);
        CryptReleaseContext(cryptProv, 0);
        CryptDestroyHash(cryptHash);
        *result = dwStatus;
        return NULL;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < cbHash; i++)
    {
        strHash[i * 2] = hex[hash[i] >> 4];
        strHash[(i * 2) + 1] = hex[hash[i] & 0xF];
    }
    CryptDestroyHash(cryptHash);
    CryptReleaseContext(cryptProv, 0);
    return strHash;
}
```